# How to show the incorrect checksum when the computed checksum did not match

Tags: checksum, cryptography

Suppose I try to verify the checksum of a file using:

```
echo '760382d5e8cdc5d0d079e8f754bce1136fbe1473be24bb885669b0e38fc56aa3  emacs-26.1.tar.gz' | \
  sha256sum --check
```

If the file is corrupt and the checksum is wrong, `sha256sum` will show this message:

```
emacs-26.1.tar.gz: FAILED
sha256sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
```

I would like to know the actual checksum of the file (i.e. incorrect checksum that caused this error message). What are my options? If possible, I do not want to compute the checksum twice (once to see the "FAILED" message, and a second time to see the incorrect checksum).

(OS: Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: I'm curious: what's the use for it?

Comment: @muru Sometimes, I download large files over an unreliable connection. I ask my neighbor to download the same file and I can determine whether or not the corruption is exactly the same as mine. Yes, I understand that I can calculate the checksum again, but checksums can take quite some time to compute on small/old computers.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code of the GNU `coreutils` implementation, the `perl` one (`shasum`) or the ast-open one (`sum`), none of them can be told to output the computed sum in verify mode.

With the `perl` one, it's easy to modify it though:

```
--- shasum.orig 2021-03-27 08:01:06.927965948 +0000
+++ shasum  2021-03-27 08:02:33.336241906 +0000
@@ -295,7 +295,7 @@
            $isOK = 1;
            $num_OK++;
        }
-       else { $rsp .= "FAILED\n"; $err = 1; $match_errs++ }
+       else { $rsp .= "FAILED (expected $sum, got $digest)\n"; $err = 1; $match_errs++ }
        print $rsp unless ($status || ($quiet && $isOK));
    }
    close(FH);
```

And then:

```
$ echo '760382d5e8cdc5d0d079e8f754bce1136fbe1473be24bb885669b0e38fc56aa3  a' | ./shasum -a 256 -c
a: FAILED (expected 760382d5e8cdc5d0d079e8f754bce1136fbe1473be24bb885669b0e38fc56aa3, got 3a1edb0672af06bc4712da1fcc00a09326e550d3f503ca41bf59d259f46afdc9)
```

Answer (score 1):

The shell script below solves the problem by saving the computed checksum into a variable. The saved checksum is then compared against the expected checksum. The saved checksum can then be displayed in an error message if needed.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

file='emacs-26.1.tar.gz'
expected='760382d5e8cdc5d0d079e8f754bce1136fbe1473be24bb885669b0e38fc56aa3'
actual="$(sha256sum "$file" | awk '{print $1}')"

if [ "$actual" = "$expected" ]; then
    echo "${file}: OK"
else
    echo "${file}: FAILED"
    echo "Expected: $expected" >&2
    echo "Observed: $actual" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

The `echo "${file}: OK` mimics the output format of `sha256sum --check`, and the `Expected: ...` and `Observed: ...` is used in place of `sha256sum --check`'s `sha256sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match` error message.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bash function like this would work?

```bsh
function check {
  file="$1"
  expected="$2"

  echo "$expected  $file" | sha256sum --check
  result=$?

  if [ $result -ne 0 ]; then
    printf "Expected: %s\n" "$expected"
    printf "Observed: %s\n" $(sha256sum "$file" | awk '{print $1}')
  fi
}
```

Here's a demonstration:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
function check {
  ...
}

file="emacs-26.1.tar.gz"
expected=760382d5e8cdc5d0d079e8f754bce1136fbe1473be24bb885669b0e38fc56aa3

if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then
  touch "$file"
fi

echo "This is what a mismatched file looks like"
check $file $expected


printf "\n--------------------------------------\n"
echo "This is what a matching file looks like"
expected=$(sha256sum "$file" | awk '{print $1}')
check $file $expected
```

Output:

```
This is what a mismatched file looks like
emacs-26.1.tar.gz: FAILED
sha256sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
Expected: 760382d5e8cdc5d0d079e8f754bce1136fbe1473be24bb885669b0e38fc56aa3
Observed: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

--------------------------------------
This is what a matching file looks like
emacs-26.1.tar.gz: OK
```

Comment: You're right.  Tried with `[ "$result" ]` and `result="$?"` but got the same problem.  `-ne` seems to handle it fine.  After years of this, the quoting rules still drive me crazy.

Comment: If you make more sense to use `if ! echo ... | sha256sum` here. You have a few more missing quotes (around `$result` and around `$(...)`). Should be `sha256sum -- "$file"`.

Comment: With the GNU implementation of `sha256sum` at  least, you need two spaces between `sum` and `file` or it won't work properly for filenames that start with space characters.

Comment: backslashes and newlines in filenames need to be handled specially as well (replaced with `\\ ` and `\n` respectively and lines prepended with backslash)

Comment: `echo` (at least some `echo` implementations, and in the case of `bash` that depends on whether the `xpg_echo` was enabled at compile time or runtime) will also mangle strings with backslashes. Best is use `printf` to output arbitrary data.

Comment: Note that the OP specified: *If possible, I do not want to compute the checksum twice (once to see the "FAILED" message, and a second time to see the incorrect checksum)*